Difficulty fitting a curve with many parameters in SciPy
I am trying to fit a curve to some data points, however the fit is not as good as I'd like. The function I am fitting too is a ZBL type screened coulomb potential.
This is my code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function(rij, a, b, c, A, B, C):
        zi = 29
        zj = 29

        rij = rij * 10**(-10)


        r1 = 1E-10  # Switching function starts to switch to full GAP
        r2 = 2.2E-10 # Swtich function goes to zero

        electron_charge = 1.60217663E-19
        epsilon_0 = 8.854187817E-12
        

        prefactor = 1 / (4 * np.pi * epsilon_0)

        coulombic_part = (zi * zj * electron_charge**2) / rij




        def switching_function(rij, r1, r2):
            # Initialize the output array with zeros, same shape as rij
            switch_func_val = np.zeros_like(rij)
            
            # Apply condition for rij <= r1 (switch_func_val = 1)
            mask1 = rij <= r1
            switch_func_val[mask1] = 1
            
            # Apply condition for r1 < rij < r2 (calculate switch function for this range)
            mask2 = (rij > r1) & (rij < r2)
            eta = (rij[mask2] - r1) / (r2 - r1)
            switch_func_val[mask2] = 1 - eta**3 * (6 * eta**2 - 15 * eta + 10)
            
            # No need to apply anything explicitly for rij >= r2 since initialized with zeros

            return switch_func_val
        
            
        def screening_function (a, b, c, A, B, C):
            
            a_divisor = 0.46848 / (zi**0.21 + zj**0.23)
            x = rij / a_divisor

            screening_func_value = a * np.exp(A * x) + b * np.exp(B * x) + c * np.exp(C * x)

            return screening_func_value
    
    
        switch = switching_function(rij, r1, r2)
        screening = screening_function(a, b, c, A, B, C)
        energy = prefactor * coulombic_part * screening * switch

        return energy * 6.242E+18 #conversion to eV






rij_data = []
energy_data = []
filename_dmol = 'dmol_Cu-Cu.dat'
with open(filename_dmol, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            parts = line.split()
            x = float(parts[0])  
            y = float(parts[1]) 
            rij_data.append(x)
            energy_data.append(y)

rij_data = np.array(rij_data)  
energy_data = np.array(energy_data)  





rij_data_zbl = []
energy_data_zbl = []
filename_dmol = 'zbl_Cu-Cu.dat'
with open(filename_dmol, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            parts = line.split()
            x = float(parts[0]) 
            y = float(parts[1])  
            rij_data_zbl.append(x)
            energy_data_zbl.append(y)

rij_data_zbl = np.array(rij_data_zbl)  
energy_data_zbl = np.array(energy_data_zbl)  



# Step 3: Use curve_fit to fit the parameters a, b, c, A, B, C
# Provide an initial guess for a, b, c, A, B, C
initial_guess = [0.3, 0.09, 0.58, -2.5, -0.29, -0.5923]
# bounds = [[0, 0, 0, -10, -10, -10], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]]

# curve_fit will fit the zbl_energy function to the rij_data and energy_data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(function, rij_data, energy_data, p0 = initial_guess, maxfev=100000)
print(np.linalg.cond(pcov))
print(pcov)

# popt contains the fitted values for a, b, c, A, B, C
a_opt, b_opt, c_opt, A_opt, B_opt, C_opt = popt

print(f"Fitted parameters: a = {a_opt}, b = {b_opt}, c = {c_opt}, A = {A_opt}, B = {B_opt}, C = {C_opt}")
plt.xlim(0,3)
plt.ylim(0, 1000)
# Step 4: Plot the original data points and the fitted curve
plt.scatter(rij_data, energy_data, label="Data Points", color="red")
plt.scatter(rij_data_zbl, energy_data_zbl, label="Data Points zbl", color="magenta")
plt.plot(rij_data, function(rij_data, *popt), label="Fitted Curve", color="blue")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

I've tried adding bounds and using sensible initial guesses based on some data i've seen in the literature, but the best fit i've got is shown here:

The red dots are the data I want to fit too, and the line is the fitted curve. Any help on how I could improve this would be greatly appreciated.

You generally don't get to decide how well data fits a curve.

I agree with Stephen. If the code and formulas are correct, there is not much you can do. Have you tried different sets of initial guesses. With many parameters, you can end up in local minima. If you do a fit only up to x=1.5, I bet the fit should look better. The question then would be, if there are good reasons to discard the data for x>1.5. Do you have errors for the datapoints? Also, your plot shows 2 sets of datapoints, but one fit ..  ?

See I'm relatively happy with the fit, however i'm just uncomfortable with the actual values of the coefficients that I get out. I suspect there is an issue with units somewhere. Discarding data from x values greater than 1.5 doesn't seem to do a great deal. The other set of points is admittedly confusing, it just represents dat points from a previously fitted ZBL.
